# Is there a better way to retrieve a random row from an Oracle table?

Tags: sql, oracle, random

Not so long ago I needed to fetch a random row from a table in an Oracle database. The most widespread solution that I've found was this:

```
SELECT * FROM
( SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE warunek
ORDER BY dbms_random.value )
WHERE rownum = 1​
```

However, this is very performance heavy for large tables, as it sorts the table in random order first, then grabs the first row.

Today, one of my collegues suggested a different way:

```
    SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM MAIN_PRODUCT
    WHERE ROWNUM <= CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MAIN_PRODUCT)*dbms_random.value AS INTEGER)
    ORDER BY ROWNUM DESC

) WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

It works way faster and seems to return random values, but does it really? Could someone give an insight into whether it is really random and behaves the way as expected? I'm really curious why I haven't found this approach anywhere else while looking, and if it is indeed random and way better performance wise, why isn't it more widespread?

Comment: Use `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE warunek AND ROWNUM =1`. Of course you will get the same row when you execute the query multiple times but in principle you get a random row.

Comment: Saw this approach too, but sadly it doesn't fullfill my needs (the random rows are fetched and then passed along for a SOAP request in a test scenario, meaning the query will be executed multiple times)

Comment: Your explanation of why the first query is slow is incorrect. The inner query takes a long time because it takes a long time to generate a different random number FOR EACH ROW. Oracle will NOT order ALL the rows of the inner query according to the random number; instead, it is able to push the outer ROWNUM = 1 condition inside the inner query - it will return just the row with the minimum random value, it will NOT order ALL the rows by the random values. The second approach is better because it only needs to generate ONE random value.

Comment: *"Oracle will NOT order ALL the rows of the inner query according to the random number; instead, it is able to push the outer ROWNUM = 1 condition inside the inner query "* @mathguy really?? that sounds not very logical check what the [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) says as you are saying that the optimize rewrits `SELECT * FROM
( SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY dbms_random.value )
WHERE rownum = 1​ ` into `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE rownum = 1​ 
ORDER BY dbms_random.value`?? which is not true as those queries do not mean the same thing.

Comment: @RaymondNijland - no, that is not what I am saying. You can't rewrite the query without an inner query - outer query structure. Rather what I explained is how the query is interpreted internally. If I say "order this set" and then later I say "give me the row where the xyz value is minimum" I won't really order everything in the set. I will inspect the xyz value in each row, one by one; whenever I find a lower value than previously recorded, I will overwrite the "recorded" row and move on. I don't need to order all the rows by xyz. And indeed that's how the Oracle runtime works.

Comment: *"no, that is not what I am saying. You can't rewrite the query without an inner query"* That is what you mean as i meant with *"optimizer rewrite"* a interpreted internally (changed) query @mathguy that is what you mean with *"it is able to push the outer ROWNUM = 1 condition inside the inner query"* what not really makes sense with a Pseudocolumn if the Oracle optimizer would do that, a normal table column would make sense to push down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second code you have

```
    SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM MAIN_PRODUCT
    WHERE ROWNUM <= CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MAIN_PRODUCT)*dbms_random.value AS INTEGER)
    ORDER BY ROWNUM DESC

) WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

is excellent, except that it will get subsequent elements. `dbms_random.value` is returning a real number between 0 and 1. Multiplying this with the number of rows will provide you a really random number and the bottleneck here is counting the number of rows rather then generating a random value for each row.

Proof

Consider the

**0 <= x < 1**

number. If we multiply it with n, we get

**0 <= n * x < n**

which is exactly what you need if you want to load a single element. The reason this is not widespread is that in many cases the performance issues are not felt due to only a few thousands of records.

EDIT

If you would need k number of records, not just the first one, then it would be slightly difficult, however, still solvable. The algorithm would be something like this (I do not have Oracle installed to test it, so I only describe the algorithm):

```
randomize(n, k)
    randomized <- empty_set
    while (k > 0) do
        newValue <- random(n)
        n <- n - 1
        k <- k - 1
        //find out how many elements are lower than newValue
        //increase newValue with that amount
        //find out if newValue became larger than some values which were larger than new value
        //increase newValue with that amount
        //repeat until there is no need to increase newValue
    while end
randomize end
```

If you randomize k elements from n, then you will be able to use those values in your filter.

Comment: Thank you for dispelling my doubts :)

Comment: @Tohuvabohu you are welcome. If any answer solves your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer. I think either mine, Gordon Linoff's and Raymond Nijland's answer would look good as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is the (possibly) the most simple query possible to get the results. 
But the `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MAIN_PRODUCT` will table scan i doubt you can get a query which does not do that.

**P.s** This query assumes not deleted records.

**Query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM
 MAIN_PRODUCT 
WHERE
 ROWNUM = FLOOR(
   (dbms_random.value * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MAIN_PRODUCT)) + 1
 )
```

`FLOOR(
   (dbms_random.value * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MAIN_PRODUCT)) + 1
 )`

Will generate a number between between 1 and the max count of the table see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ab0560dedd0dec4ffc90d45ff443f3a9) how that works when you refresh it.

**Oracle12c+ Query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM
 MAIN_PRODUCT 
WHERE
ROWNUM <= FLOOR(
   (dbms_random.value * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MAIN_PRODUCT)) + 1
)
ORDER BY 
 ROWNUM DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

Comment: Thanks, it somewhat works too, but is much slower than `SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM MAIN_PRODUCT
    WHERE ROWNUM <= CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MAIN_PRODUCT)*dbms_random.value AS INTEGER)
    ORDER BY ROWNUM DESC

) WHERE ROWNUM = 1;`
and sometimes doesn't return any row at all

Comment: *"Thanks, it somewhat works too, but is much slower than "* Yes also it's is hard if not impossible to suggest something else without knowing table structures / indexes and example data... *"and sometimes doesn't return any row at all "* indeed this query assumes not deleted records forgot to mention @Tohuvabohu

Comment: @Tohuvabohu if you have Oracle12c+ you can also try the second query.

Answer (score 1):

The key to improving performance is to lessen the load of the `ORDER BY`.

If you know about how many rows match the conditions, then you can filter before the sort.  For instance, the following takes about 1% of the rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM tabela
      WHERE warunek AND dbms_random.value < 0.01
      ORDER BY dbms_random.value
     )
WHERE rownum = 1​ ;
```

A variation is to calculate the number of matching values.  Then randomly select a smaller sample.  The following gets about 100 matching rows and then sorts them for the random selection:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT a.*, COUNT(*) OVER () as cnt
            FROM tabela a
            WHERE warunek
           ) a
      WHERE dbms_random.value < 100 / cnt
      ORDER BY dbms_random.value
     ) a
WHERE rownum = 1​ ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer :)

Comment: I disagree. There is no `order by` load in the first query in the original post. The row limiting clause ROWNUM = 1 in the outer query will cause the innner query to simply ignore the ORDER BY directive; instead, the execution engine will just keep track of the generated value for each row, and whenever that value is less than the current minimum, it will replace the previously saved row with the current one. The first solution is slow due to the `DBMS_RANDOM` load (needing to generate a different random number for each row) - that is a slow operation.